# Controlling the position of dropdow submenu

Tags: sub-menu

can someone explain how I can modify the position of a submenu so that it can be higher than it is now (eg closer to the menu bar, without the gap between the header and the dropdown box of the submenu...see attached picture)?
[image]

Here is the code underlying the submenu:
[image]

Comment: I added the coding where the submenu appears. Hope this can help offer a more specific advice. Also I am not sure how to do what you suggest, but if I do as you suggest still the submenu box would appear quite big I reckon, a bit out of proportions

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the current code, you could try the folllowing:

Use padding-top over the `<ul>` tag and colour the `<li>` tag's background colour in the dark grey. This way you avoid using `top` / `margin-top`.